# how to remove duplicate entries from the output xml file?

Tags: xslt

XSL stylesheet is generating repeated output. Below is an example of it. The same thing is repeated thrice. In the first set of xml, i am only getting value of first attribute and in the secound from second attribute and so on.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <obj>
    <desc value="113662176"/>
    <index value="" name="MATERIALNUMMER"/>
    <index value="" name="DOKUMENTENART"/>
    </obj>

    <obj>
    <desc value=""/>
    <index value="66260383180" name="MATERIALNUMMER"/>
    <index value="" name="DOKUMENTENART"/>
    </obj>

    <obj>
    <desc value=""/>
    <index value="" name="MATERIALNUMMER"/>
    <index value="Fertigungsauftrag" name="DOKUMENTENART"/>
    </obj>
```

I have also tired with xsl when and choose but the output was same. below is an example input xml with some attributes.

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
    <root>
    <document> 
    <field   level = "document" name = "Fertigungsauftragsnummer" value = "113662176"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "Materialnummer" value = "66260383180"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "Dokumentenart" value = "Fertigungsauftrag"/>
    </document> 
    </root>
```

below is the xsl style sheet which i am using for conversion. In the xsl template if i use match="/*" i dont get repeated output neither do i get values of xml attributes. It seems that for every xsl if we have one specific output. How can I make xsl style sheet to compile only once the input xml for all the xsl if statements?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:transform version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/root/document/*">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:text>obj</xsl:text><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:text>desc value="</xsl:text>
     <xsl:if test="@name='Fertigungsauftragsnummer'">   
     <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
     <xsl:if test="@name='Materialnummer'"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
     <xsl:if test="@name='Dokumentenart'">  
     <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
     </xsl:if>
     </xsl:if>
     </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"/&gt;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:text>/obj</xsl:text><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:transform>
```

Expected output is shown below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <obj>
    <desc value="113662176"/>
    <index value="66260383180" name="MATERIALNUMMER"/>
    <index value="Fertigungsauftrag" name="DOKUMENTENART"/>
    </obj>
```

Answer (score 0):

You current approach of using `xsl:text` with disable-output-escaping is not the right approach when building XML. You should be writing out the XML tags directly. It looks like you want to convert `document` elements into `obj` elements so you should have a template like this

```
<xsl:template match="/root/document">
  <obj>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="field" />
  </obj>
</xsl:template>
```

(In your current XSLT, you were converting `field` into `obj` which is why you got three of them).

It also looks like you want fields with name "Fertigungsauftragsnummer" into a `desc` element, so just create a template for that.

```
<xsl:template match="field[@name='Fertigungsauftragsnummer']">
  <desc value="{@value}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the syntax for the attributes using curly braces. These are known as [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates).

For the other two fields, you can share a common template, as it looks like you just want to make the name upper-case in both cases

```
<xsl:template match="field">
  <index value="{@value}" name="{translate(@name, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/root/document">
    <obj>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="field" />
    </obj>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field[@name='Fertigungsauftragsnummer']">
    <desc value="{@value}"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <index value="{@value}" name="{translate(@name, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks a lot for your answer. It has helped me a lot to some extent.  You have defined two templates here, Is there a way to diffrentiate between the two templates, as I have to add same value in 3 different tags. For ex: 
   <obj>
      <desc value="113310301"/>
      <type value="SDG"/>
        <indexlist>
         <index value="113310301" name="FERTIGUNGSAUFTRAGSNUMMER"/>
         <index value="66260383180" name="MATERIALNUMMER"/>
         <index value="Fertigungsauftrag" name="DOKUMENTENART"/>
      </indexlist>
      <docfile name="113310301.pdf"/>
   </obj>

Comment: Hi Tim,with the help of mode I achieved what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your support. Regards,Amrita